# Adding user to ownership in addition to another user

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, apache-http-server

I had some problems with permissions, the programmers of my website wanted me to add the admin user to the apache group and then set some permissions. My knowledge of Linux is quite limited, so I found the following online:

```
chown -R apache:apache /path/to/webserver/www 
chmod -R g+rw /path/to/webserver/www
```

This worked perfectly, and all was well for few days (BTW, I used "apache" instead of www-data since I'm on CentOS).
Now, they're saying they can't upload files to that folder since it is owned by apache user, while they want it to be owned by apache AND admin user.

How do I add 'admin' to ownership as well in addition to 'apache'?

Thanks

Edit:

I used the `mount` command and got the following:

```
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=16377400k,nr_inodes=4094350,mode=755)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=755)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuacct,cpu)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
/dev/sda3 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,quota,usrquota,grpquota,data=ordered)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=35,pgrp=1,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
/dev/sda5 on /tmp type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/sda2 on /boot type ext2 (rw,relatime)
```

Next, I used the `tune2fs -l | grep acl` and got the following:

```
Usage: tune2fs [-c max_mounts_count] [-e errors_behavior] [-g group]

        [-i interval[d|m|w]] [-j] [-J journal_options] [-l]

        [-m reserved_blocks_percent] [-o [^]mount_options[,...]] [-p mmp_update_interval]

        [-r reserved_blocks_count] [-u user] [-C mount_count] [-L volume_label]

        [-M last_mounted_dir] [-O [^]feature[,...]]

        [-E extended-option[,...]] [-T last_check_time] [-U UUID]

        [ -I new_inode_size ] device
```

I am not sure whether it's ok or not - how do I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

According to the traditional file permission that's not possible: a file has only a single owner.

Your approach including *admin* to *apache* group should work.

However most modern filesystems support [ACLs](http://linux.die.net/man/5/acl). If you want to use ACLs to give another user read (`r`) and write (`w`) permissions then you can use the command [setfacl](http://linux.die.net/man/1/setfacl):

```
setfacl -m user:admin:rw /path/to/webserver/www
```

Even if the filesystem you are using supports ACLs, check that it is mounted with support for ACLs. In that case you need to issue the command `mount` and get the dev related to the filesystem, for example:

```
[root@centos]#mount

/dev/sda3 on / type ext4 (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext4 (rw)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)
```

The dev for the root filesystem is `/dev/sda3`.

Now with the command `tune2fs` you have to issue the command:

```
[root@centos]tune2fs -l /dev/sda3 | grep acl

Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
```

In this case it has `acl`enabled. If it wasn't the case then you have to modify */etc/fstab* to include `acl`on the options as it is explained [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/448872/how-to-get-acl-working-in-centos).

Comment: thank you for the quick reply, I tried these and I posted the outcome in the original question since it was too long for the comment, can you please check and let me know how I should proceed?

Comment: @MAR My bad!!!. The command must be `tune2fs -l /dev/sda3 | grep acl` where */dev/sda3* is the root filesystem.

Comment: Oh damn I just used "setfacl -m user:admin:rw /path/to/webserver/www" and it deleted the whole folder... what do I do? Edit: actually it might just be hidden from me for some reason, but I can't access the website as well... How do I reverse it?

Comment: @MAR use `getfacl /path/to/webserver/www` to check which groups and users have permissions, if you are `root` then you will have access and it won't be hidden  from you.

Comment: @MAR `setfacl -b /path/to/webserver/www` should restore the ACLs to the prior state.

Comment: Ok I just restored the permissions through DirectAdmin panel and I see it again now, but still I don't really get how I can set both admin and apache as owners?... or maybe add them to the same group?

Comment: @MAR add *admin* to *apache* group.

Comment: I added it. 'id admin' gives back: uid=1001(admin) gid=1002(admin) groups=1002(admin),1000(apache)

Answer (score 0):

[jcbermu](https://superuser.com/users/318069/jcbermu) gived the answer with ACL rule:

```
setfacl -m user:admin:rw /path/to/webserver/www
```

But this way **admin** wouldn't be allowed to enter www directory

Correct ACL is:

```
setfacl -m user:admin:rwx /path/to/webserver/www
```

With this command programmers will be granted only rights to create their own files in this very directory. They neither can modify other newly created files within www nor create files in subdirectories of www. So you need to add the following ACL rule as default:

```
 setfacl -dm user:admin:rwx /path/to/webserver/www
```

The best way is to modify existent files/subfolders in www to conform to new ACLs and adding default rules for newly created files/subfolders. In this case use the command below instead of the two above:

```
setfacl -Rm d:u:admin:rwX,u:admin:rwX /path/to/webserver/www
```

Here rules for existent and newly created files and folders are combined in one string.

**-Rm**   **R**ecursively **m**odify ACLs

**u:admin:rwX** Set ACLs for user **admin** for existing files and (sub)folders of starting **www** folder

**d:u:admin:rwX** Set ACLs for user **admin** for newly created files and (sub)folders

You can remove all additional ACLs at any time using

```
setfacl -Rb /path/to/webserver/www
```