# Why is a user only added to one group at a time?

Tags: linux, permissions, apache-http-server, centos, administrator

I'm trying to add Apache and a user called `admin` to the same group on CentOS.
When I run `id admin` I get groups 1000 (apache) and group 1002 (admin), when I run `id apache` I get groups 1000 (apache) and 1003 (access).

I see that they're both members of the 1000 group (apache), but when I try to add admin to the 1003 (access) group as well via `usermod -G access admin`, it deletes admin from the apache group for some reason (so then when I run 'id admin' I get groups 1002 and 1003, but it is not listed as part of 1000 anymore).

Is there like a limitation of the number of groups a user can be a member of? If not, how do I put them in the same group?

My problem is due to permissions issues - in a specific folder, which is owned by 'admin', for instance, when I try to create a new directory or upload a file with the admin user I am able to do so. However, when I try to do that using the apache user I can't.

Edit: Output for getfacl:

```
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: home/admin/domains/xxx/public_html/xxx/xxx
# owner: apache
# group: apache
user::rwx
user:apache:rwx
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:apache:rwx
default:group::rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

14th of April edit:

```
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: home/admin/domains/public_html/xxx/xxx
# owner: apache
# group: apache
user::rwx
user:admin:rwx
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:admin:rwx
default:group::rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mar, as I've always [answered to your previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/1058548/adding-user-to-ownership-in-addition-to-another-user/1058662#1058662), you needn't add users to any groups to get access to files in specific folder and its subfolders because POSIX ACLs are quite enough to solve such problems.

Use the command below:

```
setfacl -Rm d:u:apache:rwX,u:apache:rwX /path/to/your/folder
```

From now on user apache (and admin) can do anything he wants in this folder and it's subfolders but nobody else.

**-Rm**   **R**ecursively **m**odify ACLs

**u:apache:rwX** Set ACLs for user **apache** for existing files and (sub)folders of starting **folder**

**d:u:apache:rwX** Set ACLs for user **apache** for newly created files and (sub)folders

You can remove all additional ACLs at any time using

```
setfacl -Rb /path/to/your/folder
```

Comment: What filesystems support ACL's? The man page says it "fiddles" with permission bits on unsupported FS's, and then errors if it doesn't "fit" completely

Comment: I've tested and been using it for ext4.

Comment: @OlegBolden Thank you for the help, however after trying this command, I'm still unable to create folders within that specific folder when I am logged in to DirectAdmin with the user admin...?

Comment: Show me the output for `getfacl /your_folder`

Comment: @OlegBolden I can't add it in the comment for some reason so I edited the main post and added the output at the bottom. Thank you!

Comment: Remove all ACLs with `setfacl -Rb /your/folder` command and enter this command for **admin** access `setfacl -Rm d:u:admin:rwX,u:admin:rwX /path/to/your/folder` Also, you needn't writing attribute for apache group of this folder. Unset it using `chmod g-w /your/folder`.

Comment: @OlegBolden You are the best! thank you so much. That solved everything (hopefully ;D)

Comment: @OlegBolden I'm having a tiny problem in relation to the last - within that folder, Apache users seems to have the ability to create a directory, but can't create subdirectory. My programmers are getting this error when the website is trying to create a subdirectory at that location - 'ErrorException' with message 'mkdir(): Permission denied'. Any chance you can help? Thanks!

Comment: It shouldn't be so... Did you do some chmod or setfacl commands after setfacl command I recommended at Apr. 4? Show me getfacl of the folder within which apache can not create subfolder.

Comment: @OlegBolden No I didn't do anything further. I added the getfacl in the main post. Thanks

Comment: As a matter of fact, additional POSIX ACLs do not affect inital rights for apach user who is the owner of that folder. Since apache user's rights are `rwx`, then user **apache** can create and delete all files, dirs and subdirs, including owned by root within this folder. Therefore, may be something wrong with you website scripts.

Answer (score 4):

#### When I add admin to the access group it deletes admin from the apache group

```
usermod -G access admin
```

You are not using `usermod` correctly.

> **If the user is currently a member of a group which is not listed,
>              the user will be removed from the group**. This behaviour can be
>              changed via the -a option, which appends the user to the current
>              supplementary group list.

Use the following command:

```
usermod -G access, apache admin
```

Or:

```
usermod -a -G access admin
```

---

#### usermod(8) - Linux man page

```
-G, --groups GROUP1[,GROUP2,...[,GROUPN]]]
           A list of supplementary groups which the user is also a member
           of. Each group is separated from the next by a comma, with no
           intervening whitespace. The groups are subject to the same
           restrictions as the group given with the -g option.

           If the user is currently a member of a group which is not listed,
           the user will be removed from the group. This behaviour can be
           changed via the -a option, which appends the user to the current
           supplementary group list.
```

Source [usermod(8) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/usermod)

Comment: `usermod -a -G access admin` did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: This is a general comment.  When you modify a user's group you have to list all groups you want them to be a member of, otherwise, the command assumes your changing the user's group. Which is the reason the manual page for the command and the syntax of the command illustrates doing exactly that.  I realize the answer indicates all of that, just thought it was worth pointing out, its expected behavior.